# Unreadable Characters in Terminal after receiving a SMS with GSM2 Click and Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, at-command

I am using a GSM2 Click shield from Mikroe on my Raspberrypi to send and receive SMS. Everything works as expected. I can send At-Commands over the Screen Terminal of my Raspberrypi and I get the correct Responses from the Click shield. So sending and reading SMS works.

Now my Problem is that every time I send a SMS from my Phone to the Raspberry I get some unreadable characters. I get those even before I get the New Message Indication. Here is an example of how it looks in my Terminal:
�����}8
+CMTI: "SM",3

The Terminal is connected using a baudrate of 115200. And before I send messages to my Raspberry, I configure the Module using the following sequence:
`at+cmgf=1`
`at+cscs="GSM"`
`at+csmp=17,167,0,241`
`at+cnmi=2,1`

I already tried changing the character set and the cnmi settings (as it seems to be a problem with the Message indication) but nothing helped.

Comment: To clarify about character sets from `AT+CSCS`: this only applies to the content of *strings*, e.g. **between** double quote characters (although for a few commands there are input/output between double quote characters that formally does not count as strings, and is not subject `AT+CSCS` translation). So whatever garbage characters you receive before `+CMTI:` has absolutely no connection to `AT+CSCS`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. That explains why changing `AT+CSCS` doesn't give me a different Output. But do you have an idea why I get this garbage characters? If it is not a string, is it possible that it has nothing to do with my AT-Commands at all ? Could it be some kind of Flow control or anything like that ?